# Passing param from xsl:apply template , but the value is not reaching to the calling template

Tags: xslt

I am passing a param in the xsl:apply-templates, but the value is not getting updated at the called template
Passing this param cqrKeyw which has value 'CQR'. but in the called template the value is not getting updated. its empty I tried the declaration in this way <xsl:param name="cqrKeyw" select="."/> still the value is empty only.

```
<xsl:template match="ServiceRequest[category/coding/code[@value='services']]">
    <entry>
        <xsl:comment> Planned Procedure (V2) </xsl:comment> 
        <procedure classCode="PROC" moodCode="INT">
            <xsl:call-template name="templateId">
                <xsl:with-param name="template-ids">2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.41:2014-06-09 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.41</xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="id|identifier" mode="id" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <!-- mapped code from code -->
                <xsl:when test="code">
                     <xsl:variable name="cqrString"><xsl:value-of select = "'CQR'"></xsl:value-of></xsl:variable>
                     <xsl:text>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</xsl:text>
                     <xsl:value-of select="$cqrString"></xsl:value-of>
                    <xsl:apply-templates  select="code" mode="code">
                    **<xsl:with-param name="cqrKeyw" select="$cqrString"></xsl:with-param>**
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <code nullFlavor="NI" /> 
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <statusCode code="active" />
            <!-- mapped effectiveTime from occurrenceDateTime -->
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="effectiveTimeIVL_TS" select="occurrenceDateTime" />
            <!-- mapped author from requester-->
            <xsl:if test="contains(requester/reference/@value,'Practitioner')">
                <xsl:variable name="refId" select="substring-after(requester/reference/@value,&quot;/&quot;)"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="author" select="(//Bundle/entry/resource/Practitioner[id/@value=$refId])[1]">
                    <xsl:with-param name="time" select="meta/lastUpdated"/> 
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:if>
        </procedure>
    </entry>
</xsl:template>
```

called template

```
<xsl:template name="coding" match="coding|valueCoding" mode="code">
<xsl:param name="this" select="."/>
<xsl:param name="doc" select="/"/>
<xsl:param name="DisplayName" select="/"/>
**<xsl:param name="cqrKeyw"/>**
<xsl:choose>
  <!--  Handle special case for codes coming from NullFlavor codeSystem for v3 -->
  <xsl:when test="$this/code/@value and $this/system/@value = 'http://hl7.org/fhir/v3/NullFlavor'">
    <xsl:attribute name="nullFlavor">
      <xsl:value-of select="$this/code/@value"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="$this/code/@value">
     <xsl:choose>       
       <xsl:when test="not($cqrKeyw='CQR') and contains($this/code/@value,':')">        
          <xsl:variable name="cptOrSnomedCode" select="substring-before($this/code/@value,':')"/>           
         <xsl:attribute name="code">
           <xsl:value-of select="$cptOrSnomedCode"/> 
        <xsl:text>cqrKey value is : </xsl:text>
           <xsl:copy-of select="$cqrKeyw"></xsl:copy-of>
        </xsl:attribute>    
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>  
            <xsl:attribute name="code">
                <xsl:value-of select="$this/code/@value"/>  
           </xsl:attribute>
       </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:attribute name="nullFlavor">UNK</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$this/system/@value = 'http://hl7.org/fhir/v3/NullFlavor'">
    <!--  Do nothing when code system is nullFlavor -->
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="$this/system/@value">
    <xsl:call-template name="translate-codeSystem">
      <xsl:with-param name="this" select="$this/system/@value"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="code" select="$this/code/@value"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="doc" select="$doc"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:attribute name="nullFlavor">UNK</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$this/system/@value='http://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/rxnorm' and $DisplayName[contains($DisplayName,&quot;(&quot;)] ">
    <xsl:variable name="MedicationGenericName" select="substring-before(substring-after($DisplayName,&quot;(&quot;),&quot;)&quot;)"/>
     <xsl:if test="$MedicationGenericName">
        <xsl:attribute name="displayName">
          <xsl:value-of select="$MedicationGenericName"/>
        </xsl:attribute>          
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
  <xsl:if test="$this/code/@value and $this/display/@value and not($this/system/@value = 'http://hl7.org/fhir/v3/NullFlavor')">
    <xsl:attribute name="displayName">
      <xsl:value-of select="$this/display/@value"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

</xsl:template>

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve, post minimal but complete samples to allow us to reproduce the issue. If you use `apply-templates` (with or without parameters), templates are not called at all, instead the selected nodes or items are pushed through matching templates. If you push `Practitioner` elements then you would need to match on `Practitioner` (or some more general pattern), using `match="coding|valueCoding"` doesn't make sense to expect parameters to show up (on child/descendants?), unless you use tunnel parameters.

Comment: Note also that you have `<xsl:apply-templates mode="author" select="(//Bundle/entry/resource/Practitioner[id/@value=$refId])[1]">` (without a `mode`) but then pretend `<xsl:template name="coding" match="coding|valueCoding" mode="code">` (with a `mode`) would be "called" or used. No, with that template belonging to a named mode, that apply-templates with no mode will not used that template.

Comment: I am passing this from the 1st code snippet <xsl:with-param name="cqrKeyw" select="$cqrString"></xsl:with-param> and trying to read the value in the code snippet <xsl:param name="cqrKeyw"/>, but I am not getting the value there

Comment: Issue resolved with the below code changes
 <xsl:with-param name="documentType" tunnel="yes" >CQR</xsl:with-param>  and  <xsl:param name="documentType" tunnel="yes"/>

Answer (score 1):

Your example is incomplete.

This line of code

```xml
<xsl:apply-templates  select="code" mode="code">
...
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

... has the effect of selecting `code` elements which are children of the context node, and applying templates to those elements (in the mode named `code`). But the template in your example does not match elements named `code`. It only matches elements named `coding` or `valueCoding`.

Please revise your question to create a small but complete example, including sample XML input and an attempt which invokes a template with `apply-templates` and a `param`.